# Windows 7 change Buttons ( CMD MAC )

Tags: windows-7, command-line, mac

I have Windows 7 and Macintosh and I use Macintosh Keyboard.
But, on Mac keyboard have "CMD" which I want to use like "CTRL" on Windows 7, how can I do that?

Comment: I want this for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

For WIndows, you can use a program like [Sharpkeys](http://www.randyrants.com/2006/07/sharpkeys_211.html), or by doing a [fairly basic Registry hack](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-caps-lock-key-in-windows-vista/).